# What are the last 2 gates for on Animus Island?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

According to the [wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Desmond%27s_Journey), there are only five "Desmond's Journey" memories (warning: spoilers on that page).  However, if you look around the area where the five memories are located, there are two more gates present.
[image: Animus Island Gates]

The gate on the far left is the fifth memory, and the other two are currently empty.  I assume they aren't being put there for no reason, so what's their purpose?  Is it for DLC in the future, or are they already used for something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would Guess DLC, or just make people ask the question.

I have all the Animus Fragments, completed all sequences 100%, and they haven't activated.

Comment: Yes, most probably an upcoming DLC. Let's wait and see! :)